# Shuffle songs in music player

Tags: android, random, shuffle, indices, android-music-player

I’m just starting Android development and Java, and this is my first app to get acquainted with Android development.  I’m almost done with the app, the only thing left is shuffling songs. I tried many steps to get it right, and I’ve scoured the web and SO for related question, yet I still can’t get it right.

This snippet of code is in my Service class, Playlist is passed from Main Activity:

```
public void setPlayList(ArrayList<SongModel> playlist) {
         playList = playlist;
         //Arraylist of integer to hold the number of indices
         list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         for(int i =0; i <= playList.size();i++){
         list.add(i);
   }

 Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(System.nanoTime()));
}
```

The code below is how songs are played, this snippet is in configPlayBack() method that plays the song from the song id:

```
long item = 0; 
item = playList.get(MusicPref.isShuffle(this)? list.get(position): position).getSongId();
```

the snippet for playing next song is:

```
public void playNext() {
            position++;
            if (position >= playList.size()) {
                position = 0;
            }
        configPlayBack();
    }
```

But the songs are still playing serially.

EDIT:

```
public void configPlayBack(){
            prepared = true;
            player.reset();
           if ( playList.size()>0){
               long item = 0;
               item = playList.get(MusicPref.isShuffle(this)? list.get(position):position).getSongId();
                playItem(item);
            }
        }
        public void playItem(long item){
            Uri base = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(base, item);
            try{
                player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "Errror setting data source", e);
            }
            try{
                player.prepare();
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                ee.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error setting data source", ee);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Song corrupt or not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ee.printStackTrace();
                isReady = false;
            }
            player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    isReady = true;
                            setPlayState();
                            getAudioFocus();
                            mp.start();
                        updateNotificationPlayer();
                            updatePlayback();
                            updateSeek();
                    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            isReady = false;
                            mp.reset();
                           playNext();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: post your whole playback method

Comment: I've edited it to include the playback method @Murat K.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you are shuffling your newly created list with

`Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(System.nanoTime()));`

but you are still using the old playlist

```
item = playList.get(MusicPref.isShuffle(this)? list.get(position): position).getSongId();
```

And I am not sure why you are using that line at all. Change it simply to

```
item = list.get(position).getSongId();
```

Comment: The list, is an ArrayList of Integer (ArrayList<Interger> list;) not an ArrayList of the SongModel object. I've also tried, before, creating an ArrayList of the songModel ( ArrayList<SongModel> list;) and then using what you suggested: item = list.get(position).getSongId(); it makes the shuffling work fine, but my RecyclerView item position changes. when you click a particular song, it plays another song due to the shuffled list. @Murak K.

Comment: item = playList.get(MusicPref.isShuffle(this)? list.get(position): position).getSongId();   This line checks if shuffling is enabled, if true, it gets the song index to play from the shuffled list. If false, it uses the normal position. At least that's how i think it should work. But for some reason, it is not working.

Comment: @JohnSmith Well, you asked for shuffled list. If your `RecyclerView` does not fit into it, that is another problem and you should create a question for that.